# Transcript has time in UTC

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

Just got invited to a chat and received the notification on Stack's INBOX

> [image: INBOX with invite to chat]

Once clicking on it in, i can the transcript with time in UTC  which is one hour before my time zone

> [image: Before joining the chat]

Then i click join room and the time is as expected (my timezone)

> [image: After joining the chat]

Comment: No, that's not a bug. The transcript shows time in UTC.

Comment: Why do we want to know the time in UTC there?

Comment: Because the transcript itself is based on a UTC day. If you were to see your local time in the transcript, you would get really weird results. Something posted today in a UTC day could be posted yesterday in a negative timezone, or tomorrow in a positive. It would add a compexity layer to site serving instead of allowing SE to serve static transcript pages for historical archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In transcript you see time in UTC, but when you enter the room you see local time.

Showing time in UTC is very common here for content rendered on serverside. Server doesn't know your local timezone. And the other thing is that rendering same time for all users simplifies caching.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a bug. While chat will display your local time correctly when you are in the actual chat room, the chat **transcripts** shown in your inbox are displayed in UTC time. That is what you are seeing here and it is by design.